# How to create a function to find the number of the element is obtained when calling the function in Lua?

Tags: lua

Example: If I have a table: `a = {12313,1231311,12312,112,1123}`
Now, I need to know what 12313's ordinal number is in this table

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the table is not sparse and is numbered.

- `haystack` is the table to search in,
- `needle` is the value to look for.

```lua
function search( haystack, needle )
    for key, value in ipairs( haystack ) do
        if value == needle then
            return key
        end
    end
    return nil -- not found. Added for clarity, not really necessary.
end
```